# FlashDevelop runtime Overhead

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

Today I met a big headache that seems nothing to do with my code.

When I tested my game and set frame rate is 60, but even when my game was in idle, the fps still stayed at 30. I check the game in my colleague's FlashDevelops, they all working very well at fps 60. Then I use adobe scout to test the game and find my FlashDevelop seems to do lots of expected runtime overhead at all time but once it is running not under FlashDevelop, it is back to fps 60 in Scout. If the games was running without relying on the FlashDevelop, it works perfect at fps 60, only happened when I tested the game in FlashDevelop.

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, happens to me also. I do not know what cause it, but to me, it happens when I run as debug version. When I run as release, everything is fine.

Comment: I created a empty project with fps counter and set the fps to be 60 in the project, it is running at 30

Comment: I got the same in debug, it is ok in release or debug without flashdevelop

Comment: No, I haven't fixed it, but it's not really a problem. It runs on 60 if it's on release, but not always. Anyway, this is probably a problem with the Flex SDK, so there is nothing much we can do about it. Try posting on FlashDevelop forum, maybe someone there can help.

Comment: It is very important for me. I need to do massive optimization for my game with adobe scout. when u check it in scout, most usage is taken up with this overhead, we can't tell the right reason for causing the performance.

Answer (score 0):

In order **to avoid Other Overhead or Runtime overhead** on Adobe Scout with Flash Develop IDE, set the compile flag for *Advanced Telemetry* and *Advanced Telemetry Password*.

`-advanced-telemetry=true -advanced-telemetry-password=123456`.

Then on Adobe Scout, click on **Edit > Preferences... > General tab > Password to unlock protected SWFs** -> put 123456 then click OK

Happy debugging!